# How to use a while loop instead of a foreach loop

Tags: php

I currently have a loop:

```
foreach($this->rows as $row):
....
endforeach;
```

Is this possible to put into a while loop?

Comment: @user2661760 - Since this is really basic stuff, perhaps you should pick up a good book about php? You could easily have found your answer checking out the documentation for a while loop: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can do like this

```
$arr = $this->rows;
$size = sizeof($arr);

$i=0;
while($i<$size)
{
  $row = $arr[$i];

  // your work

  $i+=1;

}
```