# PHP using while or anyother loop in place of foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, while-loop

`Foreach` loop does not work properly after a certain number so I want to replace it with `while`  or `for`  loop. is it possible to achieve the same thing with a while loop or any other method?

```
<?php foreach( $health_posts as $post ):setup_postdata($post); ?>

//content

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: here is a reference to the same question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332294/how-to-use-a-while-loop-instead-of-a-foreach-loop

Comment: can't attach setup_postdata

Comment: Why do you think that setup_postdata will work in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, didn't see that is a WordPress question.
If the loop doesn't work in a bigger $health_posts array, you can chunk that array, and loop over the chunks.
I found this code snipped in an answer here: [Github](https://gist.github.com/amaxwell01/3792582)

```
<?php
$chunks = array_chunk($health_posts, 12);

foreach ($chunks as $row) : ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach ($row as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
      <div class="col-xs-2"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
      <?php
    endforeach; 
    ?>
  </div>
```

I hope it helps.